# Sending notification automatically firebase

Tags: reactjs, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have an application that sends data to the firebase realtime database. Now I'm creating a dashboard to manage this data. At the moment I need to receive a notification on the dashboard when the user sends some new data to the firebase. I need to receive a message with the data id he sent and submit a notification similar to a social network.

I'm using FCM, I've already configured and tried to implement the onCreate () function. But when the bank is upgrading, this function is not being performed.

I'm implementing the code in the dashboard

```
  const functions = require("firebase-functions");

  const admin = require("firebase-admin");
  admin.initializeApp();

  exports.makeUppercase = functions.database
    .ref("users")
    .onCreate((snapshot, context) => {
      const original = snapshot.val();

      console.log(original);
    });
```

I'm actually lost on how to do this, I read the documentation, but I didn't quite understand the correct steps to follow. Is there anything I should do before that? Or is this method of doing wrong?

Comment: I think you have a problem with your database reference. what do you mean by " But when the bank is upgrading"?. does the user has a bank? if so you need to get that reference. for an example `.ref("/tasks/{employeeID}/{taskId}")` this reference get triggered new task 'on create'.

Comment: In my database there is only user registration. So, when I have a new user I want to receive notification on the dashboard.

Comment: try `.ref("/users/{userID}")` . this shoud work

Comment: Unfortunately it still didn't work. The makeUppercase function is not being executed.